# What did Douglas Crockford mean by 'constructed in a different window or frame'?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What does Douglas Crockford mean when he wrote the `is_array()` test saying that it will fail to identify arrays that were constructed in a different window or frame?

```
var is_array = function (value) {
    return value &&
        typeof value === 'object' &&
        value.constructor === Array;
```

Why does the following work across windows and frames?

```
var is_array = function (value) {
    return value &&
        typeof value === 'object' &&
        typeof value.length === 'number' &&
        typeof value.splice === 'function' &&
        !(value.propertyIsEnumerable('length'));
};
```

Comment: I think to string can be used in non ancient versions of ecma script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example, if you have an `iframe`, which has its own `window`, any `Array` constructed in there will fail another `window`'s test. That's because of the last condition, which assumes the current `window`'s `Array`, which is a different object.

```
var isArray = document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow.Array === Array; 
// false (wrong, it *is* an array)
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmXfB/).

The latter works through knowing that `typeof` always says an `Array` is an `"object"`, as well as looking for properties that exist on `Array`s.

However, it can *be* fooled, by constructing an object that looks like an array.

```
var isArray = is_array(Object.create({length: 0, splice: function() {}}));
// true (wrong, it *isn't* an array)
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BtaL6/).

Another method is to invoke `Object`'s `toString()` method on it, which will return the internal class.

```
var isArray = ({}).toString.call(value) == "[object Array]";
// true (correct, it's an array)
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UR99f/).

This works in a multi-`window` environment and can't be *tricked* (though there is more overhead examining it this way, but never likely to be a bottleneck).

Comment: i like your solution, short and simple, however im not familiar with technicals, more overhead as in...?

Comment: @user2167582 Basically, if you don't care about failing the multi `window` environment test, use Crockford's first `is_array()`. Last time I benchmarked them, the latter example above was a magnitude or so slower.

Answer (score 2):

I think alex's solution is better than Crockford's. This answer is to point the flaw in Crockford's solution.

See this:

I purposefully created a faulty object.

```
function Stupid(){}
Stupid.prototype.length = 0;
Stupid.prototype.splice = function () {}

var stupid = new Stupid();

is_array(stupid);
// true
```

Obviously, if you see someone setting length to the prototype, you have every right to smash their head to the wall.

But this is valid:

```
function Mediocre(){
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'length', {
        get: function () { return 42; }, 
        enumerable: false
    });
}
Mediocre.prototype.splice = function () {}

var m = new Mediocre();

is_array(m);
// true
```

So, you shouldn't try to outsmart the usual/common methods, because you can't guess what the other developers are going to do.